# SQLAlchemy - Duplicates counter column

Tags: sqlalchemy

I need some help in transforming the following query into one SQLAlchemy statement:

```
select c.id, 
c.first_name, 
c.middle_name, 
c.last_name,
cd.dups -- THIS IS A COLUMN WHICH IS NOT MAPPED THROUGH SQLAlchemy
from contacts c
inner join
(select _c.last_name, count(_c.last_name) as dups from contacts _c group by _c.last_name) cd on c.last_name = cd.last_name
group by c.id, c.first_name, c.last_name, cd.dups
```

**EDIT-1:**
Forgot to mention that I am using the ORM where my Contact object is mapped to contacts table. I'll be more specific  about what I am trying to achieve. When selecting the contacts based on a specific criteria I have to return an 'extra column' which says how many times the last_name is found in contacts table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had hard time with how a labeled column should be used.

```
subq = self.db_context.query(Contact._last_name, label('dups', func.count(Contact._last_name))) \
                .group_by(Contact._last_name) \
                .subquery('dup_contacts')
            dup_contacts = aliased(Contact, subq)

            contacts = self.db_context.query(Contact, 'dups').filter(Contact._last_name.ilike(_contact_last_name)) \
                .join(dup_contacts, and_(Contact._last_name == dup_contacts._last_name)) \
                .all()
```